# First record from record set empty. Why?

Tags: php, mysql

Why is the first record empty? It's not empty the first record becomes the second record and the first one is empty and it appears out of nowhere

This is the code

```
mysql_select_db($database_webiceberg, $webiceberg);
$query_services = "SELECT
services.dynamic_price,
services.database_price
from services
where lang=2 " ;

$services = mysql_query($query_services, $webiceberg) or die(mysql_error());
```

This part of the code is in the body

```
  <?php do { 
      $title = $row_services['dynamic_price'];
      $database_price = $row_services['database_price'];
      $id = $row_services['id_services'];

  ?>
  <tr id="<?php echo $id;?>">
   <td class="matrixItem" >
     <a href="WebDesign.php?cattegory=<?php echo $cattegory; ?>" id="nigga"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
   </td>
  </tr>
   <?php } while ($row_services = mysql_fetch_assoc($services));
   ?>
```

I deleted parts of the code in this to give it more syntax and coz the code i deleted was redundant

Comment: Instead of a `DO...WHILE`, why don't you try a simple `WHILE` ? Your current `WHILE` command is at the bottom, so the first loop might not be fetching any data yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
<?php 
while ($row_services = mysql_fetch_assoc($services)) { 
    $title = $row_services['dynamic_price'];
    $database_price = $row_services['database_price'];
    $id = $row_services['id_services'];
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo $id;?>">
    <td class="matrixItem" ><a href="WebDesign.php?cattegory=<?php echo $cattegory; ?>" id="nigga"><?php echo $title; ?></a></td>


    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

`do{}` block will be runned before `while()`  so `$row_services` is null first.

use simple while or write `$row_services = mysql_fetch_assoc($services)` before `do`

```
 <?php 
    while ($row_services = mysql_fetch_assoc($services)): 

        $title = $row_services['dynamic_price'];
        $database_price = $row_services['database_price'];
        $id = $row_services['id_services'];
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo $id;?>">
        <td class="matrixItem" >
            <a href="WebDesign.php?cattegory=<?php echo $cattegory; ?>" id="nigga"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile;  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `while` syntax instead of `do...while`. In the `do...while` the result is not  fetched on first iteration and you have a blank record.

if you use `while`, you will have data from at very first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Its just nothing, coz you fetch it in `while ($row_services = mysql_fetch_assoc($services))`
and it works after first execution, So at that time, record is null or empty only. Use an entry-controlled looping :)